# Prevent multiple database call (read from memory)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have database with a product table. The table only has 7 items and would prefer to be able to store them all in memory instead of the database, but I would still like the ability to use the active record type inference.  find_by, first, last, .where(some query param).

Is this possible in rails 5.2 with Postgres 11?

I was reading about sqlite3 memory, but not sure if this is a best use for it. I would also prefer not to switch my whole app over to sqlite.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can use [Array#find](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/find) and [Array#select](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/select)  instead of `find_by` and `where` respectively

Answer (score 1):

Lazy way:

config/application.rb

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    def things
      @things ||= Thing.all 
    end
  end
end
```

`Rails.application.things.detect { |thing| thing.name == "Cool Name" }`

Note that your associations will still be loaded from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have so few rows in the products table, you should not need to worry much about hitting the DB to fetch them.  There are many ways to avoid unneeded database queries, but we can't recommend that you not use the DB for this model without knowing the relations and how they might be used in your app. If you don't need relational data model or mvc for products then you can use a constant array and as Max has mentioned in the comments, you can use Enumerable methods on normal Array such as:

```
PRODUCTS ||= [
  [name: 'tennis_balls', description: 'you need em'],
  [name: 'racquets', description: 'have at least one'],
  [name: 'sneakers', description: 'run fast with these']
].freeze

class Product
  def self.by_name(name)
    PRODUCTS.flatten.find{|a| a[:name] == name.to_s}
  end

  def self.by_names(names)
    names.map{|name| by_name(name)}.compact
  end
end
```

Now you can do

```
Product.by_name('sneakers')
# or 
Product.by_name(:sneakers)
```

Or an array of names:

```
Product.by_names([:racquets, :sneakers])
```

Answer (score 0):

The official rails docs provide detail on [low level caching](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) which sounds like it might work

You can set a static key name and a long expiration time